Does a voltage regulator convert voltage to current?
I have 12V, 1.3A input power, that I want to convert to 5V, 3A. Is it possible with a voltage regulator? If not, what should I use?

The label "Current: 1.3A" on your power supply is telling you that it can supply between 0A and a maximum of 1.3A. It's the load that will decide its own current, and you must never attach a load that may try to draw more than the supply is capable of providing, 1.3A in this case.
This will damage the supply, probably:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Vs is the supply, and the load R1 is a simple resistance, and Ohm's law can tell us what current it would draw when connected across a 12V source. As you can see, the ammeter measuring current reading 1.5A, above the limit that your supply is able to provide. This is a contrived example, because very few loads are simple resistances like this, but my goal was to illustrate the problem faced by the supply. In this case the supply might just break, or it might lower its output voltage, to save itself.
To finish the illustration, and show how a load could have 12V across it, and draw less than 1.3A, here's a less demanding load on the same supply:

simulate this circuit
Your power supply would be fine with this 10Ω load.
A voltage regulator, like a power supply, doesn't choose what its load's current will be, the load does. So all you know is the voltage of its output. However there are two kinds of voltage regulator.
The first kind, linear, cannot output more current than flows into their input. If your load wants 5V at 3A, and you have a 12V supply capable of only 1.3A, then a linear regular used to drop voltage from 12V to 5V will also have the constraint of a 1.3A maximum output.
The kind you require, then, is a "switching" regulator, also called a DC-DC converter, a "buck" converter in this case, since you want to reduce voltage. These regulators will be more power efficient, in that power in will be closer to power out. This means that buck converters are actually able to output more current than their source can supply.
Power is calculated as the product of voltage and current. If the load draws at most 3A, with 5V across it, then it will be consuming at most:
$$ P_{OUT} = 5V \times 3A = 15W $$
The power fed into the regulator will be slightly more than 15W, because no regulator is 100% efficient. Let's say your regulator has an efficiency of 80%:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{OUT} &= P_{IN} \times 80\% \\ \\
I_{OUT} \times V_{OUT} &= I_{IN} \times V_{IN} * 0.8 \\ \\
I_{IN} &= \frac{I_{OUT} \times V_{OUT}}{V_{IN} \times 0.8} \\ \\
&= \frac{3A \times 5A}{12V \times 0.8} \\ \\
&= 1.56A \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
That's more than your supply can handle, so an 80% efficient buck converter cannot solve your problem. The efficiency \$K\$ required to successfully power your load will be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
K &= \frac{P_{OUT}}{P_{IN}} \\ \\
&= \frac{5V \times 3A}{12V \times 1.3A} \\ \\
&= \frac{15.0W}{15.6W} \\ \\
&= 96\%
\end{aligned}
$$
That exists, but it's really tough ask, and it's hard to find switching regulators that efficient, and are affordable.
Use the maths I just showed you to find the some kind of compromise. The easiest solution is either to reduce load current somehow, or to get a slightly beefier supply. Sorry the news isn't better.

I assume from your question that your output has to be 5V, and current between 0 and 3A, depending on the load. A voltage regulator, by definition, can do that.
I assume from your question that your output has to be 5V, and current between 0 and 3A, depending on the load. A voltage regulator, by definition, can do that. You have 12V * 1.3A = 15.6W as your input, and you are requesting at most 5V * 3A = 15 W of output. Therefore if you pick a voltage regulator that is about 15/15.6 = 96% efficient, it should be able to cover your range of use.
Another point to keep in mind is what type of input is supplied. Because on the market there exist both voltage regulators and current regulators, you have to first determine what type of input you have.

Welcome to the forum, gcinani. I didn't downvote but can see a few reasons that it might. You haven't given much of a clue how the 5 V output would be achieved given the 1.3 A limit on the 12 V supply. (The solution is described in Simon and Chester's answers.) Remember you can always edit your answer to improve it.

@transistor, thank you for your feedback. With all due respect, please not that the OP asked if it is possible to lower the voltage from 12 V to 5 V with a voltage regulator. A succinct answer shouldn't be required to explain how.

Sure, but an LM7805 is a "voltage regulator" but wouldn't work in this application. The OP might not know that or not understand why. You're pointing the OP in the direction of a buck converter but haven't made it clear.

The input power available is 15.6 W, and the required output power is 15 W. This means the DC-DC Buck Converter needs to be at least 96% efficient.
The ROHM Efficiency of Buck Converter application note lists the basic mechanisms of power loss in a Buck Converter, which impact the overall efficiency.

I agree that @Alireza932 needs a buck converter but with the given specifications he will draw all the power the input supply can handle. It will certainly get hot. He'd better get another supply that can do a bit better. I would try to get a supply that can handle at least 5V 4A when I need 5V 3A.
